# How to join two data frames and add fields in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, merge

I have two dataframes for example,

```
DF1
+----+-------+------+------+
|id  | value1|value2|value3|
+----+-------+------+------+
|  1 |10     |20    |30    |
|  2 |20     |30    |40    |
|  3 |30     |40    |50    |
+----+-------+------+------+

DF2
+----+-------+------+------+
|id  | value1|value2|value3|
+----+-------+------+------+
|  1 |100    |200   |300   |
|  2 |200    |300   |400   |
|  3 |300    |400   |500   |
+----+-------+------+------+
```

I want to merge these two dataframes by id and at the same time add the columns with the same name in the two dataframes together. So what I want is something like this

```
+----+-------+------+------+
|id  | value1|value2|value3|
+----+-------+------+------+
|  1 |100+10 |200+20|300+30|
|  2 |200+20 |300+30|400+40|
|  3 |300+30 |400+40|500+50|
+----+-------+------+------+
```

Merging part is fairly easy with spark

```
df1.join(df2,Seq("id"))
```

Is there an efficient way to add the two columns with the same name in the two dataframes together as above with scala and spark.

Answer (score 1):

In scala it is quite easy to manipulate columns in a generic way. You can do it like this.

```scala
// extract the names of the columns to sum
val cols = df1.columns.filter(_!="id") 

// join and sum
val result = df1
    .join(df2,Seq("id"))
    .select( col("id") +: cols.map(c=>df1(c)+df2(c) as c) : _*)
```